# NavigationStack crashes when changing path in iOS 17.1.2

Tags: swiftui, crash, swiftui-navigationstack, swiftui-navigation, swiftui-path

In my SwiftUI app I'm using `NavigationStack` with `navigationDestination` modifier to navigate user between views. In my `AppState` I'm holding a state for array of `NavigationPath` that are triggering state in my `ContentView` with Combine's `Publisher`:

```swift
struct NavigationState: Equatable {
    var path: [NavigationPath] = []
}
    
enum NavigationPath: Hashable {
    case view1
    case view2
    case view3
    case view4
}
```

To navigate between views I have a `NavigationState` extension. These are the methods I call on `appState` to change `path` array:

```swift
extension AppState.NavigationState {
    mutating func navigate(to destination: AppState.NavigationPath) {
        if !path.contains(destination) {
            path.append(destination)
        }
    }
    
    mutating func pop() {
        _ = path.popLast()
    }
    
    mutating func popToView2() {
        path = [.view2]
    }
}
```

This is how the `ContentView` looks like:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var navigationPath: [AppState.NavigationPath] = [.view1]
    
    var body: some View {
            NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
                View1()
                    .navigationDestination(for: AppState.NavigationPath.self) { path in
                        switch path {
                        case .view1:
                            View1()
                        case .view2:
                            View2()
                        case .view3:
                            View3()
                        case .view4:
                            View4()
                        }
                    }
            }
            .onReceive(navigationPathUpdate) {
                self.navigationPath = $0
            }
    }
}

// MARK: - State Update

private extension ContentView {
    var navigationPathUpdate: AnyPublisher<[AppState.NavigationPath], Never> {
        container.appState.updates(for: \.navigationState.path)
    }
}
```

`updates` method is just for updating the state and I guess it's not important to explain in detail.

In the end the code works perfect on all iPhones and in all iOS versions except iOS 17.1.2 (tester's iPhone 14 Pro). When the user calls `popToView2` app crashes. I've tried to comment out this call and in that case app is not crashing for the tester, so the only guess left is that `popToView2` does something bad. I have a crash log in Xcode but it doesn't point the exact line of code where the problem is. `popToView2` is used after log out to show login screen again.

[image: Crash log in Xcode]

Did anyone experience something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use multiple `navigationDestination` modifiers for each type of value, not a single modifier with an enum/switch inside. These are designed to be declared throughout your `View` (model) struct hierarchy. The path has been specially designed to be able to hold different types unlike array.